# Why are runouts not recorded in cricket?

Tags: cricket, statistics

In international cricket, the number of catches taken by a player is recorded, but not the number of runouts effected by a player, even though effecting a runout is as important as taking a catch.

Is there a specific reason for leaving out runouts from the record book?

Comment: The problem for mine with the second answer here is that clearly sometimes (often even) a catch is also the fault of the batsman and the fielder just happens to be the one standing near by. So by that rationale fielders wouldnt have their career catches recorded within their records either. I have always had an issue with the lack of run out dismissals being recorded. A direct hit run out affected by a brilliant piece of individual athleticism can be a game changing effort. The result of this individual effort should be recorded within the players career records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's tradition more than anything, combined with the fact there can be ambiguity over who actually effects the runout when more than one fielder is involved e.g. outfielder throws to wicketkeeper who takes the bails off.

The only online reference I can find is at http://www.dangermouse.net/cricket/statistics.html in the Fielding Statistics section, but even here all it says is that this a tradition.

Comment: Not only can there be doubt about who really effected the runout, but sometimes it's entirely the batsman's fault. The fielder just happens to be the one near the ball when it happened.

Answer (score 0):

Historically runouts have not been recorded in cricket, however the good people at the [ACS](http://acscricket.com/) have gone through the old newspaper reports and attributed runouts retroactively to players, although the ICC do not recognise these, they are largely respected by scorers.

In modern [T20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty20) International [and most domestic] Cricket, which has largely been televised, it usually is, at least, noted .... like this from the CPL the other day.

> RJ Peterson   run out (Brathwaite/Cottrell)   7   9   0   0   77.77
>     18.2 Cottrell to Pollard, comes round the wicket, low full toss wide outside off, powers it down the ground, long-on comes around and fires
>   it to the bowler who removes the bails. KP wants to keep the strike as
>   they comes back for the second, Peterson way short of his crease 101/6

Comment: While this is all true, it doesn't actually answer the question which is *why* the players contributing to runouts aren't/weren't recorded.